# Making a map on android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

im trying to make an app on android just a typical map that utilizes a smartphones GPS and i am planning on using Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm.

What i plan to do is make a top view map of an island and gather latitude and longitude data for each intersection on the islands road from my gps, join the  image (the map of the island i made) with the latitude and longitude data then implement Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm.

any suggestions?

how will i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

first
Activity file

GoogleMap googleMap;
 googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)

> This guide is a quick start to adding a map to an Android app. [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) is the recommended development environment for building an app with the Google Maps Android API.
>
> Step 1. Download Android Studio
>
> Step 2. Install the Google Play services SDK
>
> Step 3. Create a Google Maps project
>
> Step 4. Get a Google Maps API key
>
> Step 5. Hello Map! Take a look at the code
>
> Step 6. Connect an Android device
>
> Step 7. Build and run your app

---

Enabling GPS:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart(); // Always call the superclass method first

// The activity is either being restarted or started for the first time
// so this is where we should make sure that GPS is enabled
LocationManager locationManager =
(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (!gpsEnabled) {
// Create a dialog here that requests the user to enable GPS, and use an intent
// with the android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS action
// to take the user to the Settings screen to enable GPS when they click "OK"
}
}
```

Hope this helps!